# Getting and error when using CAST to convert Varchar to Int

Tags: sql, casting, subquery

I'm writing a query to work out the amount of movie directors that have worked on more than one movie. I've taken the value of a subquery but when I run it I get an error 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Co_op' to data type int'.

```
SELECT 
    Dir.title_id, 
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(dir.dir_id) 
          FROM [DBAmovies].[dbo].moviedir dir
          WHERE Dir.dir_id = dir.dir_id) AS int) AS 'Co_op' 
FROM 
    [DBAmovies].[dbo].[directors] Dir
JOIN
    [DBAmovies].[dbo].moviedir MovDir ON MovDir.dir_id = Dir.dir_id
JOIN 
    [DBAmovies].[dbo].movies Mov ON MovDir.title_id = Mov.title_id
WHERE 
    'Co_op' > 1
```

Why is my `CAST` failing?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Not sure why you are casting a count, which is already an integer, to an integer? Also, if you want to filter on an aggregate then you need a HAVING clause, not a WHERE clause

Comment: Ignore my last statement about the HAVING clause. Your WHERE clause is trying to convert the literal value 'Co_op' to an integer so it can compare to the value 1

Comment: Correct quoting uses `[]` not `''`, in any case an underscore does not need quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Correct quoting uses `[]` not `''`, and in any case an underscore `_` does not need quoting.

Other issues:

- Unless you are on a case-sensitive server, `Dir` and `dir` are the same thing, so the subquery would never have been correct anyway.
- You can't use a column from the `SELECT` in the `WHERE`. It would need to be in a subquery.
- You can also improve this query by using a window function.

```sql
SELECT
    Dir.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        Dir.title_id, 
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dir.dir_id) AS Co_op
    FROM 
        dbo.directors Dir
    JOIN
        dbo.moviedir MovDir ON MovDir.dir_id = Dir.dir_id
    JOIN 
        dbo.movies Mov ON MovDir.title_id = Mov.title_id
) Dir
WHERE
    Co_op > 1;
```

Having said that, I *suspect* you may have just wanted normal aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
    Dir.dir_id, 
    COUNT(*) AS Co_op
FROM 
    dbo.directors Dir
JOIN
    dbo.moviedir MovDir ON MovDir.dir_id = Dir.dir_id
JOIN 
    dbo.movies Mov ON MovDir.title_id = Mov.title_id
GROUP BY
    Dir.dir_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Or as a joined aggregation

```sql
SELECT
    Dir.dir_id, 
    md.Co_op
FROM 
    dbo.directors Dir
JOIN (
    SELECT
        MovDir.dir_id,
        COUNT(*) AS Co_op
    FROM
        dbo.moviedir MovDir
    JOIN 
        dbo.movies Mov ON MovDir.title_id = Mov.title_id
    GROUP BY
        MovDir.dir_id
) md ON md.dir_id = Dir.dir_id
WHERE
    md.Co_op > 1;
```